# How do you capture (or clip) a webpage that has protection?

Tags: capture

How do you capture (or clip) a webpage that has protection? (e.g., a web page like http://blog.daum.net/kipoworld/3490)

Somebody suggested below that you can simply SAVE the entire webpage (presumably on your hard drive). Yes, that is possible. BUT you still can't do other useful things from the saved page. For example, you still can't print the page for some technical reason (try to print the page at the link that I provided above), nor can you clip it with popular bookmark tools (like Readability or Pocket). You are back to square one - of being helpless - even after saving the page.

In any event, is there any solution?

Comment: You may need to give some more details. I copy and pasted text from that site as well as saving an image from there.

Comment: I think that you're talking about right clicking and stuff. You could try to disable scripting since it is javascript/ajax that is causing the error.

Comment: Aaah, I don't run scripts by default :) That would explain it working for me.

Comment: You could hit "Ctrl+U" on your keyboard (Chrome or Firefox, not sure about IE/Opera/Safari) to see the source and find the image or text you want.  It won't be formatted though.

Answer (score 0):

If by protection, you mean disabled right click, then in order to make right click function as usual you can disable Javascript. If that leads to desired content not loading properly at all, there is always the source HTML markup which you can look at and find what you need.

Comment: Yes, disabling Javascript resulted in the desired content not loading up at all. How do you find "the source HTML markup" that I can look at?

Comment: http://kb.iu.edu/data/agao.html this is a start...

Answer (score 0):

You could simply try to save the complete webpage from the browser, and then just to look for what you want inside the source files you save.

Or you could print the page to a pdf.

Or you could simply take a screenshot of what you want.

Since you don't specify WHAT exactly you want to keep (an image, some text, etc), i can't give further options.

Comment: I want to be able to archive the entire web page. Yes, I can save the complete webpage, but from that point, you can't do anything useful. For example, you still can't print the page (can you print the page at the link that I provided above?), nor can you clip it with popular bookmark tools (like Readability or Pocket). You are back to square one even after saving the page.